# Dynamically adding values from selectOneMenu to returned bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, selectonemenu

I have an old Java application using JSF1.2

I am returned a bean from the backend layer:

```
<p>You have &pound;${myvalue}</p>
```

Which displays as You have £100

I have a selectOneMenu on the same page:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value=“#{value}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select a value.">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel=“Please Select" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue=“1" itemLabel=“£1" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue=“2" itemLabel=“£2" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue=“3" itemLabel=“£3" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue=“4" itemLabel=“£4" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue=“5" itemLabel=“£5" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

When a user selects a value from the drop down, how can i add it to my bean above an display to the user:

```
<p>You will have &pound;${myvalue + itemValue}
```

So, if itemValue 1 is selected, it will display:

```
You will have £101
```

Comment: Is this the real code? This code doesn't compile when copy'n'pasted plain. As to the concrete question, you basically just need to print `#{myvalue + value}`, but this is relatively too obvious and straightfoward, that I fail to see how you failed to see that.

Comment: @BalusC - Because when im trying the above, if myvalue is 100, then You will have &pound;${myvalue + itemValue} displays 200.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  If `bean.currentValue=100` and I select the `<f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="£2" />` the result will be 102.

```
<h:form>         
<p>You have &pound;${bean.currentValue}</p>
            <br />
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedValue}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select a value." id="menu">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Please Select" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="£1" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="£2" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="£3" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="£4" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="£5" />
  <f:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}" render="result"></f:ajax>
</h:selectOneMenu>
            <br />

You will have &pound;<h:outputText id="result" value="${bean.currentValue + bean.selectedValue}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: I tried this on jsf 1.2 and it fails, bigtime, can you please explain this?

Comment: I'm using JSF 2, so not sure... How does it fail?  Does it print the wrong value or does it not update the value after a selection, or what??  Provide more detail.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to tempt you in improving your answer or think about it. The original question was for 1.2, so an answer that only works on 2.0 is kind of not relevant...

Comment: without telling us more detail how it fails, I'm not sure we can provide any assistance.  You mention above in your comment to BalusC ..."displays 200" Is that the wrong value, or the desired value? Is 200 the result of perhaps the code incorrectly adding 100 to 100?  I'm looking for clarity on your issue.